# Recommended Algorithim for time based clustering

Tags: algorithm, k-means, data-science, hierarchical-clustering

I am not very knowledgeable on time based clustering and wondering if any algorithms are well suited for my use case.

I have a set of exertion data (range from 0-500) and I want to cluster them along time intervals.

My problem is that I want to find point the points of time where there is major exertion differences on the time interval.   I will know exactly how many grouping their should be (e.g. 5 separate clusters) but wont know where one ends and the next one starts.

Is there a good algorithm to apply in this case?   I was looking at K-Means but it appears to be very good at clustering disregarding the time and I am more looking for the boundaries looking at exertion data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get good results from a dynamic program. For each interval `[i, j)`, let `C(i, j)` be a loss function that is lower when the interval values are more likely to be one cluster. Then letting `L(k, r)` be the minimum loss for up to `k` clusters of elements `[0, r)`, we have equations

```
L(1, r) = C(0, r)
L(k, r), k > 1 = min over s in [0, r) of L(k-1, s) + C(s, r).
```

If there are `O(1)` values of `k` needed, evaluating these equations with memoization takes `O(n^2)` time and `O(n)` space where `n` is the number of samples.

A plausible first choice for `C(i, j)` would be the statistical variance of the samples in that interval. Naively, this requires `Theta(n^3)` time to compute for each interval, but [Welford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_Online_algorithm) can be used to compute variance online if you iterate `s` from its greatest value to its least, so the overall algorithm would still be `O(n^2)`.